# Load an array variable from a file

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have the following code which uses an array to write the result to file.
I want to create another array to read the celebrities array from another file.

```
<?php
require("class.XMLHttpRequest.php");
function hot($news){
 $url="https://localhost/search.aspx?search=".$news.""; 
 $ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
 $ajax->setRequestHeader("Cookie","Cookie: host");
 $ajax->open("GET",$url,true);
 $ajax->send(null);
 if($ajax->status==200){
  $rHeader=$ajax->getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
  if(substr_count($rHeader, "Present!")>0) { return true; }
 }else{ return false; }
} 
$celebrities = array('britney','gaga','carol');
$filename = 'result.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
foreach($celebrities as $celebrity)
{
    if(hot($celebrity)) { fwrite($handle, "{$celebrity}\r\n"); };
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```

I would also like to load the `$celebrities` array from a file instead of

```
$celebrities = array('britney','gaga','carol');
```

I couldnt get this to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen('array.txt', "r"); 
if ($handle) { 
   while (!feof($handle)) { 
       $celebrities[] = fgets($handle, 4096); 
   } 
   fclose($handle); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I'd love to see the `hot` function.

Comment: Please don't yell at us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code. What exactly doesn't work? Any error messages?

Why are you reading the file into an array? My suggestion:

```
$read_file = fopen('array.txt', 'r');
$write_file = fopen('result.txt', 'a');

while(!feof($read_file))
{
    $celebrity = trim(fgets($read_file));
    if(hot($celebrity)) { fwrite($write_file, "{$celebrity}\r\n"); }
}

fclose($write_file);
fclose($read_file);
```

Comment: your ideea is great, that's actually what i want to do , load from a a file then write to another, you example doent give any errors but my result.txt is empty

Comment: in your example it seems like after reading the file the info doesnt go in variable celebrity so i gues that's y nothing is written

Comment: Sounds like for some reason you cannot read `array.txt`. Maybe something about file encoding, line endings or permissions. Sorry, I don't have time anymore now. I will check this question again later.

Comment: i think it misses the old foreach($celebrities as $celebrity) line there,

Comment: found it ! i must use $celebrity = trim(fgets($read_file)); and also replace $handlewith $write_file

Comment: Oh, yeah, stupid that I still had `$handle` in there! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$celebrities = file('array.txt'); // possibly add an array_filter()

// OR
$celebrities = explode('\r\n', file_get_contents('array.txt'));
```

Comment: I used the wrong file from your question, you probably want result.txt, but it was really only meant as an example. If you have one celebrity per line in a file either should work.

Comment: yeah but i want to take an array from a file then use the function and the result goes to another file

Comment: If you use file('array.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); then the newline characters and blank lines will be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're separating each array entry by a newline/carriage return, you should read in the contents of the file line by line and assign each to your array, which it looks like you're doing. Perhaps declaring the array before you use it will help, i.e. `$celebrities = array();` before your loop. Otherwise it looks like $celebrities is getting redefined every time your loop iterates.

If you provide more information on what is not working (parse error? contents of the array?) then I could provide a more detailed answer.

If the code doesn't give an error, print out the contents of the array `print_r($celebrities);` and show us your output.

Comment: "$var" and "{$var}" is the same in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that for work in OSX linux and Windows:

```
$content = file_get_contents($file_name);
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('fileName.txt'));
```

The `PHP_EOL` return the end of line for current OS.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I store variables in a file:

```
<?php

    return array(
        'db' => array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '3306',
            'database' => 'someDatabase',
            'username' => 'someUsername',
            'password' => 'somePassword'
        )
    );
```

Then I assign the variables to $MariaDB with this command:

```
$MariaDB = include("read.php");
```

This is how an example of I access the variables:

```
$dsh = "mysql:host=" . $MariaDB['db']['host'] . ";dbname=" . $MariaDB['db']['database'];
$dbh = new PDO($dsh, $MariaDB['db']['username'], $MariaDB['db']['password'] );
```